# Unnecessary HTML output with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I am scraping the `HTML` of the `h1` tag. The `selector` only targets the `h1` tag but when I print it, it also prints an unnecessary `HTML` with the `h1` tag.

```
import requests 
from scrapy.selector import Selector

r = requests.get('https://www.catholicgallery.org/mass-reading/310122/')
resp = Selector(text=r.text)
h1 = resp.xpath('//h1[@class="tdb-title-text"]').get()
print(h1)
```

output:
[image]

Comment: If You already installed Scrapy. Can You post output of `scrapy version -v` command in your python environment?

Comment: I have Scrapy : 2.4.1

Comment: This is not enough.
I mean - complete log output from specified command `scrapy version -v` . It should include versions of all related libraries: lxml, mentioned libxml2, cssselect etc.

Comment: Here is the complete list

Scrapy       : 2.4.1
lxml         : 4.6.3.0
libxml2      : 2.9.12
cssselect    : 1.1.0
parsel       : 1.5.2
w3lib        : 1.21.0
Twisted      : 21.2.0
Python       : 3.8.11 (default, Aug  6 2021, 09:57:55) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
pyOpenSSL    : 20.0.1 (OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021)
cryptography : 3.4.7
Platform     : Windows-10-10.0.19043-SP0

Comment: Ok. You have `libxml2 : 2.9.12`
I know that at least in one case downgrading this library to version  `2.9.10` - solved this issue
https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/issues/228#issuecomment-913465379

Comment: When I use this command "pip install --upgrade libxml2==2.9.10" it says "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2==2.9.10
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libxml2==2.9.10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is affected by this issue:
[scrapy/parsel: HTML code extraction from node is not working #228](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/issues/228)

It is reported that downgrading `libxml` to  2.9.10 can solve this issue.

Comment: which command should I use? 
When I use this command "pip install --upgrade libxml2==2.9.10" it says "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2==2.9.10 ERROR: No matching distribution found for libxml2==2.9.10"

Comment: libxml2 is not a python package - it can't be installed/updated by pip.

Comment: I see, so how am I suppose to downgrade it?

Comment: the easiest way to update change id - by using `conda` in compartible environment.
Or You can install older version of `lxml` (assuming that it will be based on older version of `libxml`